# Subprocess doesn't respect arguments when using multiprocessing

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, bash, subprocess

The main objective here is to create a daemon-spawning function. The daemons need to run arbitrary programs (i.e. use `subprocess`).

What I have so far in my `daemonizer.py` module is:

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep
from subprocess import call, STDOUT


def _daemon_process(path_to_exec, std_out_path, args, shell):

    with open(std_out_path, 'w') as fh:
        args = (str(a) for a in args)

        if shell:
            fh.write("*** LAUNCHING IN SHELL: {0} ***\n\n".format(" ".join([path_to_exec] + list(args))))
            retcode = call(" ".join([path_to_exec] + list(args)), stderr=STDOUT, stdout=fh, shell=True)
        else:
            fh.write("*** LAUNCHING WITHOUT SHELL: {0} ***\n\n".format([path_to_exec] + list(args)))
            retcode = call([path_to_exec] + list(args), stderr=STDOUT, stdout=fh, shell=False)

        if retcode:
            fh.write("\n*** DAEMON EXITED WITH CODE {0} ***\n".format(retcode))
        else:
            fh.write("\n*** DAEMON DONE ***\n")


def daemon(path_to_executable, std_out=os.devnull, daemon_args=tuple(), shell=True):

    d = Process(name='daemon', target=_daemon_process, args=(path_to_executable, std_out, daemon_args, shell))
    d.daemon = True
    d.start()

    sleep(1)
```

When trying to run this in bash (**This will create a file called `test.log` in your current directory.**):

```
python -c"import daemonizer;daemonizer.daemon('ping', std_out='test.log', daemon_args=('-c', '5', '192.168.1.1'), shell=True)"
```

It correctly spawns a daemon that launches `ping` *but it doesn't respect the arguments passed*. This is true if shell is set to `False` as well. The log-file clearly states that it attempted to launch it with the arguments passed.

As a proof of concept creating the following executable:

```
echo "ping -c 5 192.168.1.1" > ping_test
chmod +x ping_test
```

The following works as intended:

```
python -c"import daemonizer;daemonizer.daemon('./ping_test', std_out='test.log', shell=True)"
```

If I test the same `call` code outside of the `multiprocessing.Process`-target it does work as expected.

So how do I fix this mess so that I can spawn processes with arguments?

I'm open to entirely different structures and modules, but they should be included among the standard ones and be compatible with python 2.7.x. The requirement is that the the `daemon` function should be callable several times asynchronously within a script and produce a daemon each and their target processes should be able to end up on different CPUs. Also the scripts need to be able to end without affecting the spawned daemons of course.

As a bonus, I noticed I needed to have a `sleep` for the spawning to work at all else the script terminates too fast. Any way to get around that arbitrary hack and/or how long do I really need to have it wait to be safe?

Comment: Please define what "doesn't respect the arguments" means.  Is `ping` launched with *different* arguments? Or is it launched and the process ignores the arguments you just passed? In this case please show the actual output you get and what you'd expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arguments are being "used up" by the printing of them!

First, you do this:

```
args = (str(a) for a in args)
```

That creates a generator, not a list or tuple.  So when you later do this:

```
list(args)
```

That consumes the arguments, and they will not be seen a second time.  So you do this again:

```
list(args)
```

And get an empty list!

You could fix this by commenting out your print statements, but much better would be to simply create a list in the first place:

```
args = [str(a) for a in args]
```

Then you can use `args` directly and not `list(args)`.  And it will always have the arguments inside.

Comment: Haha, that was a silly mistake. I think I was so frustrated with the `sleep` issue that I missed that one.